# Remove button's curved edge and adjust panel's text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[JS FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ettmujvg/19/)

I've tried everything I could think of the remove the curved edge of the top and bottom buttons but they won't work. I tried this :

```
.btn {
    border-radius: 0;
    font-size:25px;
    padding:0;
}
```

but this only removes part of the curved edge, before and after : 
[image]

and one more thing is the panels, I tried to set the height of the panel, but now the text isn't placed center horizontally and vertically :

```
.panel-title {
    height:8px !important;
}
```

[image]

How do I fix those 2 issues? Thanks alot!

P/s: since I was asking, I'm also dying to hear your opinions, or tips that can help me to make the site looks like this : https://www.behance.net/gallery/6355085/dashboard-analytics . I create the site following this idea but I think I'm missing somethings because mine looks like a mess :(

Comment: those buttons are probably in a container, which still has some border-radius. remove that border-radius too!

Comment: And for the panel text, set a line-height which equals the panel height.

Comment: I don't know why this happens but i would use a <nav> with list items for these buttons instead of <button>

Answer (score 2):

add this

```
.btn-group-vertical>.btn:first-child:not(:last-child) {
   border-top-right-radius: 0px;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ettmujvg/21/)

Answer (score 2):

Check for first and last child in you bootstrap. This is from your fiddle.

```
 .btn-group-vertical > .btn:first-child:not(:last-child) {
        border-top-right-radius: 4px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
    }
```

as you can see there is a border-radius. try using code inspector or something similar to see the classes applied to your element

Answer (score 1):

Add `!important` to your **css** if you don't want to remove radius every where.

**Fiddle** : http://jsfiddle.net/ettmujvg/20/

**Css** :

```
body {
    background-color:#444444;
}

.panel{
    border-radius: 0 !important;   // <--- HERE
}
.btn {
    border-radius: 0  !important;   // <--- HERE
    font-size:25px;
    padding:0;
}

.btntext{
    padding:0;
    font-size:14px !important;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.btn-default {
        color:black !important;
}
.btn-custom {
    width: 100px !important;
    margin-top:0px !important;
    background-image:linear-gradient(to right, #FFF 0px, #E0E0E0 100%) !important;
}

.btn-custom a{
    color:#333 !important;
}

.pHeader-panel {
    margin-bottom : 0px;
    height:25px;
    text-align:center;
    background-image:linear-gradient(to left, #FFF 0px, #E0E0E0 100%) !important;
}

.panel-heading {
    background-image:linear-gradient(to top, #FFF 0px, #E0E0E0 100%) !important;
}


.panel-title {
    height:8px !important;
}

#pHeader
{
    position: fixed; 
    width: 100%; 
    top:0px;
}

#pLeftMenu {
   position: fixed;
   top: 25px;
}

#pBody {
    margin-top:30px;
    margin-left:105px; 
    padding-right:8px;
}

#halfHorizontalPanel {
    margin-left:0px; 
    margin-right:0px;
    background-color:white;
    border:1px solid;
    min-height:300px;
}

#lefthalfHorizontalPanel{
    margin:8px 0px; 
    margin-right:0px;
    width:49.5%; 
    background-color:white;
    border:1px solid;
    min-height:290px;
    float:left;
}


#righthalfHorizontalPanel{
    margin:8px 0px; 
    width:49.5%;
    background-color:white;
    border:1px solid;
    min-height:290px;
    float:right;
}


.btn-group-vertical-custom
{
    margin-top:0px !important;
}

.tbl-stair {
    border:1px solid;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked. Could you take a look at the panel's text too please?